# Adding scroll bar to jQuery autocomplete using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight shows how to add a scroll bar to a jQueryUI autocomplete.  It works as advertised, however, it is difficult to manage if multiple autocomplete widgets are used which have different height requirements.  For my case, I have various dialogs (all with an associated height) and have the autocomplete widgets within the dialog.

When configuring the autocomplete (i.e. `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags, ...});`), could the scroll bar and associated height be added?  Could it be done so where it takes the height setting from the parent element (i.e. the dialog)?

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to modify the autocomplete widget, add a css class to widget
here is the css

```
.fixedHeight {
    color:red;
    font-size:10px;
    max-height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

after creating autocomplete in your js add the fixedHeight class like this

```
$( "#courses" ).autocomplete({
//load autocomplete options
});

$( "#courses" ).autocomplete("widget").addClass("fixedHeight");
```

check this working  [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rampellisrinu/7zj0mpad/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the class named `.auto-complete` in `jquery-ui.css`. There you can add min-height and max height which will fix the height for minimum height and maximum height of the autocomplete box. Give it a try.

Comment: this is true but it seems that they are looking to have different Max for each pop up, this approach would change the max for all would it not? Also think its better to add another .css file and override so that with nuget update the jQuery css file will not get skipped

Comment: Yes it will. Then again, you have to identify each `auto-complete' uniquely and assign heights for them

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add the prop to the item itself when creating it. The auto complete will get the value from the css then override with the value you set. Something like

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags, ...});
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete("widget").attr("max-height", "5px");
```

^ not tested will tinker with it in a few to get a good working example

Comment: I like this solution, however, it applies the `max-height` attribute to the `input` element and not the `ul` element.

Comment: @user1032531, yeah didnt get to test that out yet. posted to get you going in a usable direction. looking at the examples you posted it seems you have this working now with the 3rd example or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

With `$("#tags2").autocomplete("widget").addClass('fixed-height');` you can add a height class to the autocomplete widget.
If you want to set a global max-height you could override the css class `.ui-autocomplete`.

See the following demo for some ways to change the height but I think the best will be addClass. (You can find the fiddle with the same code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/fwaq3dkz/2/))

```js
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

     $("#tags2").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    
    $("#tags3").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
    
    $("#tags2").autocomplete("widget").addClass('fixed-height');
   $("#tags3").autocomplete("widget").attr('style', 'max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;')
});
```

```css
 .ui-autocomplete {
     max-height: 100px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
* we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
*/
 * html .ui-autocomplete {
     height: 100px;
 }

.fixed-height {
   padding: 1px;
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags max-height set with class .ui-autocomplete:</label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags max-height set manually with class fixed-height:</label>
    <input id="tags2" />
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags max-height set with jQuery:</label>
    <input id="tags3" />
</div>
```

Comment: but scrolling using arrow up/down key through Autocomplete Table not working